# shell curl/wget truncate JSON download when run from CRONTAB

Tags: linux, shell, file, curl, wget

I am downloading a JSON file periodically in CRONTAB, the file is always truncated to the same size. If I run the same script from the shell, the file is always complete.
Both Wget and Curl truncate the file in the same way.

my script ...

```
curl  "https://opendata.paris.fr/explore/dataset/velib-disponibilite-en-temps-reel/download/?format=json&timezone=Europe/Berlin&lang=fr" >> "/home/jt/public_html/ParisBike/`date -u`.json"
```

any ideas why this would be? I am not root on the server.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you use curl's own `-o` parameter for the output filename, instead of `>>` redirection?

Comment: The same results with both curl and wget when I use their -o  -O  parameters.

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't find out why this was happening , but a workaround is to run (from the command line). the  wget or whatever in a repeating loop and then background it (I use cltr-z, bg) ...

```
#!/bin/sh
while true 

do

 # Do stuff ...

  sleep 60
done
```